# Background color and TextWrap to form in j2me

Tags: java-me

can we give the backgorung color to form and can do text wrap in form in J2ME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are starting new project means better you can go with [LWUIT Framework.](http://lwuit.java.net/) Also see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit/6165904#6165904).